# Display SQL text as Integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT 'EXAMPLE' as ENTITY
,[Posting Date] as "POSTING DATE"
,[Source No_] as "CODE"
,[Amount] as "AMOUNT"
,[Global Dimension 2 Code] as "COST CENTRE"
,[Description] as "DESCRIPTION"
***,substring([External Document No_], 8, 20), as "CLAIM ID"***
,[Entry No_] as "ENTRY NUMBER"
,datename(month,[Posting Date]) as "MONTH"
,YEAR([Posting Date]) as "YEAR"
FROM [LIVEBC].[dbo].[EXAMPLE]
where [G_L] = '2153' and [Source Code] = 'EMP'
```

The above script works, but I want to convert the *** line to an integer in order to do an order by that successfully orders as number and not text.

Comment: `cast(xyz as integer)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cast()`:

```
cast(substring([External Document No_], 8, 20) as bigint)
```

However, I might suggest a numeric/decimal instead:

```
cast(substring([External Document No_], 8, 20) as decimal(20, 0))
```

You don't have to worry about overflow.